# facing date error while extraction weeks in pandas

Tags: pandas, date, dt

I all i write the below code for getting weekdays values from calendar date in pandas dataframe. but i am getting some error

```
codetest['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(codetest['DATE'], format = '%m/%d/%y')
codetest['day_of_week'] = codetest['DATE'].dt.dt.day_name()
```

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 12

Comment: `codetest['DATE'].dt.day_name()`?

Comment: i am trying to extract days in week like 1, 2 , 3 ,4 ,5 ,6,7

Comment: I am trying to extract 7 days in a week like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: `codetest['DATE'].dt.week()`

Comment: Hi Ben, still i am getting same error after using codetest['DATE'].dt.week()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have DATE: String variable, YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

**Step 1:** Convert your "DATE" column to datetime

`codetest['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(codetest['DATE'])`

**Step 2:** Extract all required field in new column using below code

`codetest['Hour'] = codetest['DATE'].apply(lambda time: time.hour)`
`codetest['Month'] = codetest['DATE'].apply(lambda time: time.month)`
`codetest['Day of Week'] = codetest['DATE'].apply(lambda time: time.dayofweek)`
`codetest['Year'] = codetest['DATE'].apply(lambda t: t.year)`
`codetest['Date'] = codetest['DATE'].apply(lambda t: t.day)`

**step 3:** if you want your day of week in words than use map function

`dmap = {0:'Mon',1:'Tue',2:'Wed',3:'Thu',4:'Fri',5:'Sat',6:'Sun'}`
`codetest['Day of Week'] = codetest['Day of Week'].map(dmap)`